# AngularJS get custom filter in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to construct a filter for my items that I display in a table. More specifically, I'd like to filter out items by a certain property value that may change depending on a users selection. I've tried the following and it appears to work. In this case I want all cities in my country array that aren't named either Stockholm or Gothenburg.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="city in cities | filter: name:'!'+'Stockholm' || 'Gothenburg'">
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

However, I want to do this programatically using a function that constructs the filter and I can't seem to get it to work.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="city in cities | filter: getFilter()">
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
</table>

$scope.getFilter = function () {
    var filter = {};

    if (something) {
        filter['name'] = '!' + 'Stockholm';
    }

    if (somethingElse) {
        filter['name'] += ' ||' + 'Gothenburg';
    }

    return filter;
}
```

Comment: if this `name:'!'+'Stockholm' || 'Gothenburg'` got work then obviously the `getFilter` code will not work..like it will produce `{name:'!'+'Stockholm' || 'Gothenburg'}` instead of what you are expecting

Comment: you need to create a custom filter. Angular JS already has that built in. Have a look at this  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Answer (score 0):

The filter method is passed each element. You need to compare it to your condition.

```
$scope.do_not_show_these_cities = ['Stockholm', 'Gothenburg'];

$scope.getFilter = function (element) {
    return $scope.do_not_show_these_cities.indexOf(element.name) < 0;
}
```

If you change the list of cities, it will be reflected.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment you can use a **Custom Filter** which is provided by AngularJS:

The below example is a basic example which takes the first alphabet of each word and filters it and converts it to upper case.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="HelloApp">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="HelloCtrl">
<form>
  <input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
</form>
<div>{{name|titlecase}}</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Code defining custom module consisting of a filter
    // The module needs to be included as dependency for using the filter, titlecase
    //
    angular.module('CustomFilterModule', [])
        .filter( 'titlecase', function() {
            return function( input ) {
                return input.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
            }
        });
    // Angular App on this page 
    // Included CustomFilterModule as dependency
    //
    angular.module('HelloApp', [ 'CustomFilterModule'])
        .controller('HelloCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
            $scope.name = '';
        }])
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Heres a working example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Ys4pgmKVRcSRFeg8unWr?p=preview

**Note: This example is to only show how to work with the angular js custom filters, you will need to optimise and edit the code to fit your requirements.**